# How to combine node.js modules/source into one .js file, to execute inside node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a need where I need to execute node code/modules in a node app (in a sandbox) with vm.createScript / script.runInNewContext.  The host node app runs on heroku, so there is no local filesystem to speak of.  I am able to download and run code that has no outside dependencies just fine, however the requirement is to be able to include other node modules as well. (as a build/packaging step would be ideal)

There are many existing solutions (browserify is one I've spent the most time with) which get close... but they inevitably generate a single blob of code (yeah!), meant to execute in a browser (boo!).  Browserify for example generates dependencies on window., etc.

Does anyone know of a tool that will either read a package.json dependencies{} (or look at all require()'s in the source) and generate a single monolithic blob suitable for node's runInNewContext?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the solution you're looking for is the right solution. Basically you want to grab a bunch of `require('lib')`'s, mush them together into a single Javascript context, serialize that context into source code, then pass that serialized form into the `runInNewContext` function to deserialize and rebuild into a Javascript context, then deserialize your custom, sandboxed code, and finally run the whole thing.

Wouldn't it make much more sense to just create a context Object that includes the needed `require('lib')`'s and pass that object directly into your VM? Based on code from the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html):

```
var vm = require('vm'), 
initSandbox = {
    async: require('async'),
    http: require('http')
},
context = vm.createContext(initSandbox);
vm.runInContext("async.forEach([0, 1, 2], function(element) { console.log(element); });", context);
```

Now you have the required libraries accessible via the context without going through a costly serialization/deserialization process.

Comment: Well this is where I run into my Heroku no writable filesystem problem.  This package is coming in to the app via S3, and I'm walking the .zip, extracting the main file in to memory, and squirting it in to a context.  I could extract the included modules (say it isn't a core module) into ./tmp (temporarily writable) and have the NODE_PATH variable look there for a require(), but that seems error prone.  Also, if the require() isn't encountered until some later code path, the modules in the .zip will be long gone.. which is why compiling into a single file seemed ideal.

Comment: Why are you attempting to dynamically install a package? If it's needed by one of your VM scripts, it should be a dependency of your app and Heroku should be installing it for you. What would happen if you have, say, 10 different users all requiring overlapping sets of packages? Would you load some of them 10 times into memory? This approach seems very brittle and unscalable.

Comment: This is a pretty unique application of node.  (and maybe the right answer is !heroku)(or !node.. but it is an otherwise very desirable platform)  It needs to handle a controlled set of developer modules, not anticipated when the app is deployed.  They need to be able to come/go at will from an admin interface - and you're right, there's definitely an overhead of duplicate packages in memory.  At least until the packaging tool gets updated & the updated module list is included in the base slug.

Comment: I'd say that I'd go with an Amazon EC2 instance for this, so you have at least a quasi-persistent store to work with, and then [read up on using npm programmatically](https://github.com/isaacs/npm) to dynamically install/uninstall packages as needed (you could have a timeout on when it was last requested for use on when you'd want to remove it, for instance).